# Conflict when running Bundle update among gem dependencies using equals-to and twiddle-wakka against the same version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, solidus

Running across this issue using Bundle Update. Shouldn't the tilde-greater-than or twiddle-wakka and equals-to both resolve to 5.1.0?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
      In Gemfile:
        rails (= 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
          actionmailer (= 5.1.0)

        solidus_core (~> 2.5.0) was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
          actionmailer (~> 5.1.0)
```

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Delete the gemlock file and run `bundle install`. If the issue persists- post your output.

Comment: Tried it, not a difference: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 5.1.0)

    solidus_core (~> 2.5.0) was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
      actionmailer (~> 5.1.0)

Comment: Just curious- have you tried different versions of solidus_core?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing `rails` version specification to "twiddle-wakka" as well. It will let you apply bugfix updates (5.1.0 -> 5.1.1, etc) without changing `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
```

Comment: Tried doing this, gettin similar errors: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.1.6)  solidus_core (~> 2.5.0) was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.8) was resolved to 1.8.8, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0)

    solidus_core (~> 2.5.0) was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
      actionpack (~> 5.1.0)

Comment: I have no other ideas then :(